# webpack with babel-loader hide babel error stack trace

Tags: webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

We are using webpack+babel-loader and we are getting this babel stack trace on compile errors:

```
ERROR in [...]
Module build failed (from from /node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: [...]: Unexpected token, expected ")" (42:15)

 [code here]

    at Object.raise (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:6420:17)
    at Object.unexpected (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:7773:16)
    at Object.expect (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:7759:28)
    at Object.parseHeaderExpression (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10279:10)
    at Object.parseIfStatement (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10362:22)
    at Object.parseStatementContent (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10054:21)
    at Object.parseStatement (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10009:17)
    at Object.parseStatement (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:2028:26)
    at Object.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10585:25)
    at Object.parseBlockBody (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10572:10)
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

We have tried playing around with webpack's module.stats with no success. It is quite distracting as it hides the actual error in the code.

**Any way to hide the babel stack trace?**

```
"@babel/core": "^7.5.5"
"babel-loader": "^8.0.6"
"webpack": "^4.41.0"
"webpack-dev-server": "3.8.1"
```